# Why does width of depletion region decreases on increasing concentration of dopant atoms in the case of pn junction diode?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, electronics

Why does width of depletion region decreases on increasing  concentration of dopant atoms in  the case of pn junction diode ?

Comment: Well, what does the fixed charge in the depletion layer result in?

Comment: Finally got it .